# Reading from File system

Tags: c++, file, file-io

This was an excerpt from my program- I want to display the text stored on the output window. The text is stored in the file as required. However, when reading, the contents are not displayed on the screen. What change should be made?

```
ofstream out("Welcome");
out<<" WELCOME TO MAIN BANK ATM SIMULATOR "<<endl;
out<<"Select operation mode:\n1. Administrator Mode\n2. User Mode\n3. Exit"<<endl;
out.close();

ifstream in("Welcome");
char asd[100];
in>>asd;
cout<<asd<<endl;
in.close();
getch();
return 0;
```

Comment: Most of your output is going to a file named `Welcome`. Then "WELCOME" should be read from that file and displayed on the screen, but the rest won't be read or displayed.

Answer (score 0):

After "Welcome" there is a space. due to space it ending the reading. so it will only show "Welcome" if there is not space then it will show whole string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `in.get(asd, 100)` (see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get))

Answer (score 0):

I generally find it easier to stream into a string rather than an array of characters.
    std::string s;
    in >> s;
    cout<

See this topic for reading an entire file into a string https://stackoverflow.com/a/4457291/2212458